# Cofinality of ordinals

Tags: set-theory

I have to calculate these cofinalities:

$Cof({\omega_2}^{\omega_2})$=?

$Cof({\omega_2}^{\omega_3})$=?

$Cof({\omega_2}+{\omega_3})$=?

I know that:

$Cof({\omega_2}^{\omega_1})={\omega_1}$

$Cof({\omega_2})={\omega_2}$

So, I think that:

$Cof({\omega_2}+{\omega_3})=\omega_3$

but what about the other two? Is there a rule for cofinality of exponential?

Comment: Just to double-check: by e.g. $\omega_2^{\omega_2}$, you mean *ordinal* exponentiation, right?

Comment: $\omega_2+\omega_3=\omega_3$ so its cofinality is $\omega_3$, and similarly, $\omega_2^{\omega_3}=\omega_3$. So maybe you should start by asking the question of how to compute such expressions before addressing that of their cofinality.

Answer (score 3):

A useful lemma for such problems is that

> Suppose there is an *increasing* cofinal sequence of order-type $\alpha$ in $\beta$. Then $cf(\alpha)=cf(\beta)$.

Hint for proof: suppose WLOG that $cf(\alpha)=\alpha$ (why can we do this?) and let $\gamma=cf(\beta)$. Letting $f$ be the embedding of $\alpha$ into $\beta$ and $g$ be some cofinal embedding of $\gamma$ into $\beta$, let $$F: \alpha\rightarrow\gamma: \eta\mapsto\min\{\delta\in\gamma: g(\delta)>f(\eta)\}.$$ Then show that $F$ is a cofinal embedding of $\alpha$ into $\gamma$.

---

So what? Well, using the definition of ordinal exponentiation, can you find a cofinal increasing subsequence of $\omega_2^{\omega_2}$, and similarly of $\omega_2^{\omega_3}$, whose length is a regular cardinal? If so, by the lemma you've just calculated the cofinality!